# Golang json query from bitcoin api returns invalid character

Tags: json, api, go, character

Something tells me I'm not understanding json correctly. I'm trying to grab some data off http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/trades.csv?symbol=rockUSD, but my Unmarshal seems to not be able to read the json data. I'm a fresh beginner to golang (and json as well), and I'm wondering how I am able to skip that wrong character error I'm making.

My error:

```
invalid character ',' after top-level value
panic: invalid character ',' after top-level value
```

My code:

```
package main

import ("fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Prices struct {
    Data string
}

func main() {
    url := "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/trades.csv?symbol=rockUSD"
    httpresp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }
    defer httpresp.Body.Close()
    htmldata, err := ioutil.ReadAll(httpresp.Body)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic (err)
    }
    var jsonData []Prices
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(htmldata), &jsonData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic (err)
    }
    fmt.Println(jsonData)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is NOT json data at all, you'd have to write a custom parser.

Example:

```
.........
data := readData(httpresp.Body)
........

func readData(r io.Reader) (out [][3]float64) {
    br := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for br.Scan() {
        parts := strings.Split(br.Text(), ",")
        if len(parts) != 3 {
            continue
        }
        var fparts [3]float64
        for i, p := range parts {
            // bad idea to ignore errors, but it's left as exercise for the reader.
            fparts[i], _ = strconv.ParseFloat(p, 64)
        }
        out = append(out, fparts)
    }
    return
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/crfw_BsRcp)

Comment: Excellent! I am starting to understand... should have looked around more first :) Thank you very much!